# the first and the last one/ones

Tags: grammar

Which is correct? Let's look at the conversation. How person B should finish the sentence?

A: I want to buy a T-shirt, but I don't know which one.

B: The...

a) The first one and the last one is okay.
b) The first one and the last one are okay.
c) The first one and the last ones are okay.
d) The first and the last is okay.
e) The first and the last are okay.

Comment: As we are not here to do your homework, please explain what your answer is.  Please explain why that would be your answer. Please explain why this question is difficult for you.  That is three things you need to add to the question. [Edit] the question please.

Answer (score 2):

The basic construction here is...

> *X **and** Y* [TO BE] *okay*

...where the subject *(X **and** Y)* is obviously plural, so the correct form of [TO BE] is ***are***.

Written out in full, the two parts of the [compound subject](https://www.thoughtco.com/compound-subject-grammar-1689898) are ***the first T-shirt*** and ***the last T-shirt***, but it's quite natural in English to replace the "primary" noun ***T-shirt*** with the generic referent ***one***...

> *The first one and the last one are okay*

It's also quite natural in English to "delete" repeated/predictable words, so...

> *The first one and the last are okay*

...is fine because it's contextually obvious that the referent of ***last*** must be the same as that previously specified for ***first*** [one].

---

Not so obviously, perhaps, we can delete ***both*** instances of the word ***one***...

> *The first and the last are okay*

...because we already know from context what ***first*** and ***last*** refer to (strictly speaking, we're deleting ***T-shirt*** above, not ***one***).

In fact, we can delete even more...

> *The first and last are okay*

Various other less extreme deletions are possible (we don't *have* to delete ***the*** before ***last*** above, for example).

Also note that although usually we include the *first* instance of a repeated word and delete *subsequent* occurrences, it's quite possible in OP's context to retain only the *second* instance of the word ***one***...

> *The first and the last one are okay*

But I'll just point out that although we can delete the second instance of the article ***the*** above, we can't delete the first one. So...

> ? *First and the last [one] are okay* (NOT VALID)

---

There's one final point to make, regarding OP's suggestion (c)...

> *The first one and the last ones are okay*

Because this includes both ***one*** and ***ones***, this would have to refer to *more than one* "last T-shirts" (as well as one T-shirt that was looked at *first*). But if that initial ***one*** were omitted...

> *The first and the last ones are okay* (both singular ***one*** and plural ***ones*** are valid here)

...this would be ambiguous as to how many "okay" T-shirts there are. The speaker could be referring to one or more T-shirts they looked at first, ***and*** one or more they looked at last. To make it unambiguously clear he meant just the first ***one*** and the last ***one***, he could say, for example...

> *The **very** first and [the] [very] last ones are okay* (second ***the*** and ***very*** are both optional)

...but since that's a bit of a mouthful he'd only say that if it was really important to avoid the ambiguity. Perhaps he's bored with shopping, and doesn't want his partner to spend ages trying on the first half-dozen *and* the last half-dozen T-shirts all over again before making a choice!